# Running tests with specific Adaptavist label

Tags: java, testing, annotations, testng, jira-rest-api

I have gotten a request from a tester to be able to run our selenium tests that hold specific labels on Adaptavist, and I am wondering how to achieve this in the best way.

I have tried using the [Kanoah API](https://www.kanoah.com/docs/public-api/1.0/) to get all testcases with a label and have managed to get all testkeys that way. I am currently wondering if it is possible to set a custom annotation connected to these testkeys, and run all tests that contain one of the values returned from the Kanoah API in the annotation.

In this case I get the value "FEN-T1411" by using the Kanoah API, and the test below is testing that testcase.

```
@Test   
@TestKey("FEN-T1411")   
public void runTest(){ 
     doThings();
}
```

So I am wondering if this is possible, or if there is another way of doing it that is easier to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this question, here is how I solved it.

First I get all testcases with a set label:

```
String query = String.format("labels IN (\"%s\")", label);
URI url = new URI("https://jira.ouradress.se/rest/atm/1.0/testcase/search?fields=key&query=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"));
```

Using the response I constructed our DTO containing a name, projectkey, testplankey and the items:

```
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;
@JsonProperty("projectKey")
private String projectKey;
@JsonProperty("testPlanKey")
private String testPlanKey;
@JsonProperty("items")
private List<TestCaseDTO> testCaseTOList;
```

After that I use that DTO to create our testrun:

```
URI url = new URI("https://jira.ouradress.se/rest/atm/1.0/testrun");
```

After this I run each test, and at the end of each one I send the results using the AfterMethod annotation, sending some relevant information regarding the test execution:

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void afterTest(ITestResult result) {     
    TestResultsReporter.resultsCollector(result.getStatus(), result.getThrowable(), this.jiraCode, 
            getDate(result.getStartMillis()), getDuration(result.getEndMillis(), result.getStartMillis()));
}
```

I get the Result as a String (pass, fail, skip) and pass it further to the next method. Only to create a TestcaseDTO containing information a stacktrace if such exist, a result/status, an executiondate and duration.

```
URI url = new URI(String.format("https://jira.ouradress.se/rest/atm/1.0/testrun/%s/testcase/%s/testresult", getTestRunCode(), testcase));
```

While I am aware that isn't optimal, it works. It requires some work as we have to manually write our jiracode into each test. So it can be forgotten which leads to tests not being reported for the run. But without any help from anyone else this is the best I managed to create.